# I use re.sub in python3 and set count to 1,but it replaces all targets?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This my code:

```
import os,re
textFile = open('D:\\hehe.txt')
textContent = textFile.read()
print(textContent)
adjRegex = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE')
nounRegex = re.compile(r'NOUN')
verbRegex = re.compile(r'VERB')
for i in range(len(textContent)):
    if(adjRegex.search(textContent) != None):
        print('Enter a adjective')
        textContent =  adjRegex.sub(input(),textContent)
    elif(nounRegex.search(textContent) != None):
        print('Enter a noun')
        textContent = nounRegex.sub(input(),textContent)
    elif(verbRegex.search(textContent) != None):
        print('Enter a verb')
        textContent = verbRegex.sub(input(),textContent,count=0)
    else:
        break
print(textContent)
textFile.close()
```

Comment: You are not setting 1 anywhere. `count=0` gives you the default behavior. Closing this as a typo.

Comment: Could you add more info about what you intend to do with your script and issues you've faced? P.S. `camelCase` in `Python`?! It's awful :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your real code (i. e. you aren't actually using any complex regular expressions, just string matching), you could use simple `str.replace`:

```
adjRegex = "ADJECTIVE"
textContent = textContent.replace(adjRegex, input(), 1)
```

Note that then all the regexes will be mere strings.

And instead of `search`ing for regexes, you could try checking whether the substrings are present in `textContent`:

```
if adjRegex in textContent:
    # replace it!
```

Comment: Thanks,I wil have a try.

Comment: Your last suggestion is bad... if you are only interested in whether a substring is present or not use `in`: `if substring in text: <do something>`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, exactly. I was looking into the docs for more info about `replace`, stumbled upon `find` and decided to use it for actually no reason :) Sure, `in` would be better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) the wrong way.
2. Why are you iterating over every character in your text? You can
   just go line by line using `readlines()` then `replace()`
3. Put the prompt message inside `input('Enter a noun')` instead of
   printing it
4. Assign input to a variable to increase readability

Comment: Thanks,I wil fix my code.